# Can not run pyspark command from any directory on my Mac after installation of Apache Spark

Tags: macos, apache-spark, pyspark

I have installed spark on my Mac, following the instructions in the book: "Apache Spark in 24 Hours". When I am in the spark directory, I am able to run pyspark by using the command:

```
./bin/pyspark
```

To install spark I created the env variable:

```
export SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark
```

Added it to the PATH:

```
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

The book says that I should be able to run the "pyspark" or the "spark-shell" command from any directory, but it doesn't work:

```
pyspark: command not found
```

I followed instructions on similar questions asked by others on here:

I set my JAVA_HOME env variable:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

I also ran the following commands:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/:$PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH
```

When I run the env command this is the output:

```
SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark
TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=xterm-256color
TMPDIR=/var/folders/hq/z0wh5c357cbgp1dh33lfhjj40000gn/T/
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.fJdtLqZ7dN/Render
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=361.1
TERM_SESSION_ID=A8BD2144-72AD-402C-A591-5C8A43DD398B
USER=richardgray
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.cQeqaF2v1z/Listeners
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0x0:0x0
PATH=/opt/spark/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/Users/richardgray/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
PWD=/Users/richardgray
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
SHLVL=1
HOME=/Users/richardgray
PYTHONPATH=/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip:/opt/spark/python/:
LOGNAME=richardgray
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Is there something I am missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ls /opt/spark/bin` and see what binaries are available

Comment: You could just use homebrew, by the way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote that

> When I am in the spark directory, I am able to run pyspark by using
>   the command: `./bin/pyspark`
>
> You created `export SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark`

Can you please confirm that `spark directory` is indeed `/opt/spark` ?

If you execute spark from `/Users/richardgray/opt/spark/bin` please set:

```
export SPARK_HOME=/Users/richardgray/opt/spark
```

followed by:

```
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Note: If it solve your problem, you'll need to add those two exports to your login scripts (e.g. `.profile`) so the path will be set automatically

Comment: spark is indeed in /opt/spark

Comment: ls from opt/spark:

Comment: LICENSE   conf   metastore_db
NOTICE   data   python
R   derby.log  sbin
README.md  examples  scala-2.12.1.deb
RELEASE   jars   spark-warehouse
bin   licenses  yarn

Comment: That is the location from my home directory i.e richardgray/opt/spark

Comment: Try using: export SPARK_HOME=/Users/richardgray/opt/spark , and update the PATH env afterwards

Comment: @RichGray -  Wonderful :)